# salesforce mobile sdk 5.0 CORS error while rest api using force.js

Tags: javascript, salesforcemobilesdk-ios, cordova, cors, salesforce-sdk-hybrid

I'm getting the CORS error while doing REST api call on Salesforce using the new force.js library.

I've also added question on Salesforce Dev Forum: https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/ForumsMain?id=9060G000000I2jbQAC

Code:

```
// Get salesforce mobile sdk OAuth plugin

var oauthPlugin = cordova.require("com.salesforce.plugin.oauth");

// Call getAuthCredentials to get the initial session credentials

oauthPlugin.getAuthCredentials(function(creds) {
    var params = {
        apiVersion: "v36.0",
        loginURL: creds.loginUrl,
        accessToken: creds.accessToken,
        refreshToken: creds.refreshToken,
        instanceUrl: creds.instanceUrl,
        appId: creds.clientId
    };
    force.init(params);

    force.query("SELECT MobilePhone, City, CompanyName, Country, CurrencyIsoCode, Email, FirstName, Name, LanguageLocaleKey, LastName, LocaleSidKey, Phone, State, Street, Profile.name, TimeZoneSidKey, Title, Id, PostalCode FROM User WHERE Id = 'xxxxxxxxxxx'", function(resp){
        console.log(resp)
    }, function(err){
        console.log(err);
    });
},
function(error) {
    alert('Failed to authenticate user: ' + error);
});
```

I've tried the following things:

```
1. Added headers:
xhr.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', '*');
xhr.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');

2. Added metatag:
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; script-src '*' 'unsafe-inline'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *; img-src 'self' data:">

3. Added options in config.xml:
<access origin="*" />
<access origin="*.my.salesforce.com" />
<access origin="*.force.com" />
<access origin="*.salesforce.com" />
<allow-navigation href="*" />
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You did all the right configuration on the app side but you missed one on the Salesforce side. You need to register the app domain under

```
Setup: Administer > Security Controls > CORS
```

This should work. It is actually [documented fairly well](https://github.com/ccoenraets/forcejs) as part of the new force.js release.

> (*) Starting in the Spring 15 release, some Salesforce REST APIs (like
>   Chatter and sobjects) support CORS. To allow an app to make direct
>   REST calls against your org, register the app domain in Setup:
>   Administer > Security Controls > CORS.
>
> ForceJS abstracts these differences and allows you to run your app in
>   the browser and on device without code or configuration changes.

Comment: As I'm developing a hybrid application using cordova, my index.html file will run locally(file:///) not on any server. How can I add that in Setup: Administer > Security Controls > CORS

Comment: @Programmer Did you get the answer. I am also facing the same issue. I am running a Cordova app with salesforce mobile SDK facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

you can also add a simple chrome plugin https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi

and enter your host. then it will also work.